# Replace " \ " with null in JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jsonp

How can I replace all the " \ " with null in my JSON data and convet the below string to a JSON array object?

```
"[
{
    \"id\": 2,
    \"data1\": 83,
    \"data2\": 2,
    \"data3\": [
        {
            \"subdata1\": 62,
            \"subdata2\": 296,          
            \"subdata3\": 2,

        },

    ]
},
{
    \"id\": 24,
    \"data4\": 83,
    \"data5\": \"ANY\",
    \"data6\": \"VALUE\",      

}
]"
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(yourJSONstring);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with some commas that were left.

```
var x = "[
    {
        \"id\": 2,
        \"data1\": 83,
        \"data2\": 2,
        \"data3\": [
            {
                \"subdata1\": 62,
                \"subdata2\": 296,          
                \"subdata3\": 2

            }

        ]
    },
    {
        \"id\": 24,
        \"data4\": 83,
        \"data5\": \"ANY\",
        \"data6\": \"VALUE\"      

    }
    ]";

    x = JSON.parse(x).toString();
```

Comment: You can mark my answer as correct? I need some reputation.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to replace the backslashes that escape the quotes with anything. Just take the string literal and parse it as JSON. If you are receiving that text as a string, you can simply parse it twice.